# BillingClient.launchBillingFlow() returns "The item you requested is not available for purchase" on one device only, all Google accounts

Tags: in-app-billing, android-inapp-purchase

I am developing an app that uses in-app billing and have been testing on three devices: a Pixel 2 running Android 10, a Samsung Galaxy Note 4 running Android 6.0.1 and a Samsung Galaxy Note 8 tablet running Android 4.4.2. I tested first with the Google test product IDs (android.test.purchased, android.test.canceled and android.test.item_unavailable) and everything ran fine; no problems on any of the devices, so I tested using my real product ID. This time, the app ran fine on the Pixel 2 and the Note 4, but on the tablet, I get the above error when calling BillingClient.launchBillingFlow(). This happens when I'm logged on with all my testing accounts and ONLY on the Note 8.

I searched StackOverflow for this issue but found nothing that matched. Anyone experience the same problem using a 4.4.2 device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was an OS issue. After I was able to re-install the app using the opt-in link (that was a separate issue, resolved only today), the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened to me as well and the reason is that your subscription was inactive. It needs to be active in order for the `launchBillingFlow` to work. Confusingly enough, you can query then and get the information from then correctly while inactive. But, even for testing, they need to be activated in order to test the buying process.

[image]